# Passing parameter from method to OnClickListener

Tags: android, parameter-passing

I want to pass the string "Jawab" to the method Proses and to the OnClick to compare data from database and data from the EditText when i click the submit button, but the String Jawab cannot be detected in the OnClick Method. See the code below.

```
public void LoadSoal(int a, DataAdapter x)
{       
    Cursor testdata = x.getTestData(a);
    String Soal = Utility.GetColumnValue(testdata, "soal");
    String Jawab = Utility.GetColumnValue(testdata, "jawab");

    TextView textSoal = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tekssoal);
    textSoal.setText(Soal);
    Proses(Jawab);
}

public void Proses(String x)
{               
    btnsubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        int skor = 0;
        TextView textScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.teksskor);
        EditText teksJawab = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.teksjawab);

        String jawaban = teksJawab.getText().toString();

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (x.equals(jawaban))
            {
                skor = skor + 10;
                textScore.setText(skor);
            }
        else
        {
            skor = skor + 0;
            textScore.setText(skor);
        }
    }
});
}
```

}

Comment: It's a java convention to start your variables and method names in lowercase. What's the error you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
public void Proses(String x)
```

to

```
public void Proses(final String x)
```

Comment: i have used this code and there is no error, but i can't still compare the string :D maybe there's other error in the code.. -_-a

Comment: When you set the text of a TextView you must pass a String as parameter or an ID for a resource. If you pass an int (as you're doing) it will probably give an exception of resource not found. So, change your code to `textScore.setText("" + skor);`.

Comment: i think this code is working but i want to check more because the score is not changed whether the String "Jawab" and String "jawaban" is the same.. x_x

Answer (score 1):

Define your own listener

```
private class MyListener implements View.OnClickListener{
     private Context mContext;
     private String mValue;
     public MyListener(Context context, String value){
         mContext = context;
         mValue = value;
     }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v){
        //do whatever you need here
        //if you need some view, use mContext.findViewById
     }
}
```

and set the listener like

```
btnsubmit.setOnClickListener(new MyListener(this, Jawab));
```

**EDIT** also in your code, I don't think the `findViewById` will find the controls you expect because you are in the context of the listener, not in your activity context.

Comment: i have used this code, but the program is still not running.. it said that "The value of the field MenuSoal.CompareAnswer.mContext is not used".. :|

Comment: yes it is a warning, but i still can't compare the answer from the database with the answer from the EditText when i click the btnsubmit..